# android.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, firebase-realtime-database

```
package my.anupamroy.smartcanteenapp.activities;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.util.HashMap;

import my.anupamroy.smartcanteenapp.Constants;
import my.anupamroy.smartcanteenapp.R;

public class AddProductActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //ui views
    private ImageButton backBtn;
    private ImageView productIconTv;
    private EditText titleEt,descriptionEt,quantityEt,priceEt;
    private TextView categoryTv;
    private Button addProductBtn;

    //permission Constants
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE=200;
    private static final int STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE=300;
    //image pick constants
    private static final int IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE=400;
    private static final int IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE=500;
    //permission arrays
    private String[] cameraPermissions;
    private String[] storagePermissions;
    //image picked uri
    private Uri image_uri;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_product);

        //init ui views
        backBtn=findViewById(R.id.backBtn);
        productIconTv=findViewById(R.id.productIconIv);
        titleEt=findViewById(R.id.titleEt);
        descriptionEt=findViewById(R.id.descriptionEt);
        categoryTv=findViewById(R.id.categoryTv);
        quantityEt=findViewById(R.id.quantityEt);
        priceEt=findViewById(R.id.priceEt);
        addProductBtn=findViewById(R.id.addProductBtn);

        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        //setup progress dialog
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        //init permission arrays
        cameraPermissions=new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        storagePermissions=new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

        backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        productIconTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //show dialog to pick image
                showImagePickDialog();
            }
        });
        categoryTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //pick category
                categoryDialog();
            }
        });
        addProductBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Flow:
                //1.Input Data
                //2.Validate Data
                //3.Add data to db
                inputData();
            }
        });

    }

    private String productTitle,productDescription,productCategory,productQuantity,originalPrice;
    private void inputData() {
        //1. input data
        productTitle = titleEt.getText().toString().trim();
        productDescription = descriptionEt.getText().toString().trim();
        productCategory = categoryTv.getText().toString().trim();
        productQuantity = quantityEt.getText().toString().trim();
        originalPrice = priceEt.getText().toString().trim();

        //2.Validate Data
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(productTitle)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Title is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(productCategory)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Category is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(productQuantity)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Quantity is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(originalPrice)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Price is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        addProduct();
    }

    private void addProduct() {
        //3. Add data to db
        progressDialog.setMessage("Adding Product...");
        progressDialog.show();

        final String timestamp=""+System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(image_uri==null){
            //upload without image

            //set data to upload
            HashMap<String ,Object>hashMap=new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put("productId",""+timestamp);
            hashMap.put("productTitle",""+productTitle);
            hashMap.put("productDescription",""+productDescription);
            hashMap.put("productCategory",""+productCategory);
            hashMap.put("productQuantity",""+productQuantity);
            hashMap.put("productIcon","");//no image, set empty
            hashMap.put("originalPrice",""+originalPrice);
            hashMap.put("timestamp",""+timestamp);
            hashMap.put("uid",""+firebaseAuth.getUid());
            //add to db
            DatabaseReference reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
            reference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Products").child(timestamp).setValue(hashMap)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            //db updated
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(AddProductActivity.this, "Product Added...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            clearData();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            //failed updating db
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(AddProductActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });

        }
        else{
            //upload with image

            //first upload image to storage

            //name  and path of the image to be uploaded
            String filePathAndName="product_images/" + "" +timestamp;

            StorageReference storageReference= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(filePathAndName);
            storageReference.putFile(image_uri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            //get url of uploaded image
                            Task<Uri> uriTask=taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                            while (!uriTask.isSuccessful());
                            Uri downloadImageUri=uriTask.getResult();

                            if(uriTask.isSuccessful()){
                                HashMap<String ,Object>hashMap=new HashMap<>();
                                hashMap.put("productId",""+timestamp);
                                hashMap.put("productTitle",""+productTitle);
                                hashMap.put("productDescription",""+productDescription);
                                hashMap.put("productCategory",""+productCategory);
                                hashMap.put("productQuantity",""+productQuantity);
                                hashMap.put("productIcon",""+downloadImageUri);
                                hashMap.put("originalPrice",""+originalPrice);
                                hashMap.put("timestamp",""+timestamp);
                                hashMap.put("uid",""+firebaseAuth.getUid());
                                //add to db
                                DatabaseReference reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
                                reference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Products").child(timestamp).setValue(hashMap)
                                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                //db updated
                                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                                Toast.makeText(AddProductActivity.this, "Product Added...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                clearData();
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                //failed updating db
                                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                                Toast.makeText(AddProductActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(AddProductActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    private void clearData(){
        //clear data after uploading product
        titleEt.setText("");
        descriptionEt.setText("");
        categoryTv.setText("");
        quantityEt.setText("");
        priceEt.setText("");
        productIconTv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_shopping_primary);
        image_uri=null;

    }

    private void categoryDialog() {
        //dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Product Category")
                .setItems(Constants.productCategories, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                        //get picked category
                        String category=Constants.productCategories[which];

                        //set picked category
                        categoryTv.setText(category);
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }

    private void showImagePickDialog() {
        //options to display in dialog
        String[] options={"Camera","Gallery"};
        //dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Pick Image")
                .setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //handle clicks
                        if(which==0){
                            //camera clicked
                            if(checkCameraPermission()){
                                //camera permission allowed
                                pickFromCamera();
                            }
                            else{
                                //not allowed, request
                                requestCameraPermission();
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            //gallery clicked
                            if(checkStoragePermission()){
                                //storage Permissions allowed
                                pickFromGallery();
                            }
                            else{
                                //not allowed request
                                requestStoragePermission();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }

    private void pickFromGallery(){
        //intent to pick image from gallery
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent,IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE);
    }

    private void pickFromCamera(){
        //intent to pick image from camera

        //using media store to pick original image
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,"Temp_Image_Title");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,"Temp_Image_Description");

        image_uri=getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,contentValues);

        Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,image_uri);
        startActivityForResult(intent,IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE);
    }

    private boolean checkStoragePermission(){
        boolean result= ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)==
                (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        return result;//return true/false
    }

    private void requestStoragePermission(){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,storagePermissions,STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private boolean checkCameraPermission(){
        boolean result=ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.CAMERA)==
                (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        boolean result1=ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)==
                (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        return result && result1;
    }

    private void requestCameraPermission(){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,cameraPermissions,CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    //handle permission results
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if(grantResults.length>0){
                    boolean cameraAccepted=grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean storageAccepted=grantResults[1]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if(cameraAccepted && storageAccepted){
                        //permission allowed
                        pickFromCamera();
                    }
                    else{
                        //permission denied
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Camera and Storage Permissions are necessary...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
            case STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if(grantResults.length>0){
                    boolean storageAccepted=grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if(storageAccepted){
                        //permission allowed
                        pickFromGallery();
                    }
                    else{
                        //permission denied
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Storage Permission is required...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    //handle image pick results
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){

            if (requestCode==IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE){
                //get picked image
                image_uri=data.getData();
                //set to imageview
                productIconTv.setImageURI(image_uri);
            }
            else if(requestCode==IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE){
                //set to image view
                productIconTv.setImageURI(image_uri);
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

LAYOUT FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activities.AddProductActivity">

    <!--Toolbar-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_rect01">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/backBtn"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back_white" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Add Product"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--Form to input data-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp">

        <com.blogspot.atifsoftwares.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/productIconIv"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_shopping_primary"
            app:c_border="true"
            app:c_border_color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:c_border_width="1dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/titleEt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/productIconIv"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_rect02"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_title_gray"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:hint="Title"
            android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/descriptionEt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/titleEt"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_rect02"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_title_gray"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:hint="Description"
            android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/categoryTv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/descriptionEt"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_rect02"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_baseline_apps_gray"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_down_gray"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:hint="Category"
            android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/quantityEt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/categoryTv"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_rect02"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_cart_gray"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:hint="Quantity"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/PriceEt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/quantityEt"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_rect02"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_baseline_currency_rupee_24"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:hint="Price"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addProductBtn"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/PriceEt"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:minWidth="150dp"
            android:text="Add Product"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

In LOGCAT I AM getting the following errors in line number  **132,43,119**

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

```
**my.anupamroy.smartcanteenapp.activities.AddProductActivity.inputData(AddProductActivity.java:132)** at my.anupamroy.smartcanteenapp.activities.AddProductActivity.access$200(AddProductActivity.java:43) *at my.anupamroy.smartcanteenapp.activities.AddProductActivity$4.onClick(AddProductActivity.java:119)**
```

**Please Help me out of this error**
from many days i am struggling with this error

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **600** (six hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `EditText` in XML showing **PriceEt** and
in Activity its initialized as

```
 priceEt = findViewById(R.id.**priceEt**);
```

Change that from XML file either in Activity and try once.

Comment: @AnupamRoy if answer is useful for you then accept this answer it will helpful to community and us.

Answer (score 0):

You have given `PriceEt` id to the `EditText` in the **XML** but you initialized it with `priceEt` which is causing an error, Replace `priceEt` with `PriceEt` to resolve the error.

**Old code**

```
priceEt=findViewById(R.id.priceEt);
```

**New code**

```
priceEt=findViewById(R.id.PriceEt);
```